# How to user XIB make SuperView match Subview's frame? (Xcode 8)

Tags: xcode, ios-autolayout

Usually we use auto layout is base on an SuperView to set the subView .

e.g:

[image]

this means the label's frame is base on the red view, But is there a way to make redView match label's bound?

e.g. I have an label in an the redView , and the label's size is dynamic base on it's content. and I want the superView's bounds bigger than label's bounds about 10 px（top，left, right ,bottom）. so how should I set the auto layout constraint in xib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set redView constraint like this -

[image]

[image]

Now set label's constraint like this -

[image]

[image]

And don't forget to set label's noOfLines to 0.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You save me bro. the point is set the >= and <= range , to ensure the view's range!